# What is happening to my app? 'Android Studio'

Tags: java, android

I don't know what is happening to my app.

This is the java code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        configureNextButton();

    }
    private void configureNextButton(){
        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PlayButton);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SelectDifficultyActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is the xml code:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MainActTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ict_word_puzzle" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bigboss"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icboss"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />




    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/PlayButton"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="@string/play"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"

        />


    <Button
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/AbtBtn"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/about"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="28sp" />>
```

and this is the logcat:

```
2021-01-12 11:06:48.701 5132-5132/com.example.programmingwordquizgame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.programmingwordquizgame, PID: 5132
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.programmingwordquizgame/com.example.programmingwordquizgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

 at com.example.programmingwordquizgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
```

Here is the code when I click the (`MainActivity.java:15`)

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Forgot to say that when i start my app it just opening the previous app that i make and said "can't open 'name of the other app' "

Comment: `What is happening to my app?` doesn't help anyone understand your question, please use more descriptive question titles in future

Answer (score 0):

You should check styles.xml and change `Theme.ProgrammingWordQuizGame` with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` or choose parent your theme custom by `Theme.AppCompat.other...`

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

1. **File/Sync Project with Gradle files**
   or
2. **File/ Invalided catches and restart**

Comment: the exception clearly says `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: oh yes, I miss that you are right. (Error occur cause of Theme)